# Facebook PHP SDK v3 keeps using same facebook user

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have a very simple piece of code:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => 'email,user_birthday,status_update'));
if(empty($user)){
header("Location:".$loginUrl);
}
```

If I don't have a logged in user in my browser I get redirected to the Facebook log in page, and after completing the log in process I am able to post on that user's wall.

But If log out and log in again with a second Facebook account the $user object will still hold the user details of the first user.

Any idea where exactly this caching is done? I need to post on the wall of which ever user is currently signed in to Facebook on that browser..

Comment: It's a very odd behavior. I'll try here. But I belive it's something in your environment. Keep us updated.

Comment: I've tested here, and actually, it's not even logging out. Even trying to logout via Javacript.